# How to find the probability distribution function from the following Distribution function?

Tags: calculus, statistics, probability-distributions

How to find the corresponding probability distribution function for the following distribution function ?

$$F (x)=
 \left\{ 
\begin{array}{ll}
 0 & \text{if } x<0 \\
 x^2 &  \text{if }   0\leq x\leq \frac{1}{2} \\
 \frac{1}{25} \left(1-3 (3-x)^2\right) & \text{if }\frac{1}{2}<x\leq 3 \\
 1 & \text{if } x\geq 3 
\end{array} \right.$$

Comment: take the derivative

Comment: I know but i am getting confused about the points where the function is not continuous ?

Comment: Are you sure that you have written down the CDF correctly? The _formula_ is not written the way one expects a _right-continuous_ function to be written (all finite intervals should be of the form $[a,b)$, not $[a,b]$), and worse yet, as $x \to \frac 12$ from the right, $\frac{1}{25}\left(1-3(3-x)^2\right) \to -0.71$ and so the CDF is not valid.

Comment: This was given to me by my professor. Can't say if its right or wrong !

Comment: Well, _ask_ your professor whether $F(x)$ satisfies all the requirements for a CDF! In particular, ask about $F(x)$ having negative value in the vicinity of $\frac 12$.

Answer (score 2):

$$ 
F(x) =
\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{if $\,x$<0} \\
x^2, & \text{if 0$\,\leq x \leq \frac{1}{2}$}\\
\frac{1}{25}\left(1-3(3-x)^2\right), & \text{if $\,\frac{1}{2} < x < 3$}\\
1, & \text{if $\,3 \leq x $}
\end{cases}
$$
thus
$$
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
2x, & \text{if 0$\,\leq x \leq \frac{1}{2}$}\\
\frac{1}{25}6(3-x), & \text{if $\,\frac{1}{2} < x < 3$}\\
0, & \text{everywhere else}
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: This _is_ a valid pdf and the correct derivative of the $F(x)$ shown, but it does not lead to the stated "CDF" which is not a valid CDF function.

Answer (score 0):

Its pdf is 
f(x)=2x if 0<=x<=1/2
and f(x)=6/25(3-x) if 1/2